# Using xdiff functions in PHP

Tags: php, php-extension, pecl

I am running PHP7 on my CentOS server, and I understand that the `xdiff` functions need the addition of a suitable PECL package.

I have run the following:

```
pecl install xdiff-2.0.1
```

In my `php.ini` file I have tried:

```
extension=xdiff.so
```

and

```
extension=/usr/lib64/php/modules/xdiff.so
```

in both cases, I get an error when I try to use `xdiff_string_patch()`:

```
Call to undefined function xdiff_string_patch()
```

I presume that I am missing a step, but I have no idea. What do I need to do to get this working?

Comment: Check your `php -i` CLI output or `<?php phpinfo();` output to locate the currently used `php.ini` file. Is that the file that you have been adding the extension to? (`php -i | grep ini`, `php -i | grep xdiff`). Also, if you are using FPM, you should restart the service to activate changes, e.g. `service php-fpm restart`

Comment: @Tom My `ini` file is at `/etc/php.ini`, which is the file I edited. I do see a comment there which indicates that packaged files are loaded from `php.d`, which I haven’t done.

Comment: And does `php -m` indicate the presence of `xdiff`?

Comment: @Tom Not there.

Comment: What's the output of `php -i | grep xdiff`, what's the output of `stat /usr/lib64/php/modules/xdiff.so`?

Comment: @Tom `php -i | grep xdiff
Failed loading /usr/lib64/php/modules/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib64/php/modules/xdebug.so: undefined symbol: php_base64_decode
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: xdiff: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20151012
PHP    compiled with module API=20170718
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
/etc/php.d/40-xdiff.ini`

Comment: @Tom stat /usr/lib64/php/modules/xdiff.so
  File: `/usr/lib64/php/modules/xdiff.so'
  Size: 87296      Blocks: 176        IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: fd00h/64768d Inode: 412388      Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2018-09-19 18:45:21.338981510 +1000
Modify: 2016-06-01 13:44:44.562274964 +1000
Change: 2016-06-01 13:44:44.562274964 +1000

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180341/discussion-between-tom-and-manngo).

Comment: I ran pecl uninstall xdiff-2.0.1 and then pecl install xdiff-2.0.1. It seems you were right about the PHP version. I suppose that it needed to be recompiled for the newer version. Thanks for your help. Can you put this in an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, it seems that the extension library does exist and that you are using the right `php.ini`, however, the following warning pops up at running a PHP script:

```
PHP Warning: PHP Startup: xdiff: Unable to initialize module Module compiled with module API=20151012 PHP compiled with module API=20170718 These options need to match in Unknown on line 0 /etc/php.d/40-xdiff.ini
```

This warning suggests a **version mismatch between the module and your PHP binary**.

To fix this, uninstall the PECL extension and upgrade your `php-dev` binaries to the version that is appropriate for your PHP version, this depends on your distribution.

Also, it might be useful to update your PECL settings, depending on your configuration (`php -i`):

```
(sudo) pecl config-set php_ini /etc/php.ini 
(sudo) pecl config-set php_bin $(which php)
```

Comment: Thanks again for your help and persistence. It also helped with a problem with `xdebug`, which was also dated.